# Python jinja2 indentention and whitespace issue

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I have the following jinja2 template. When I render it, lines after the "endif" statement do not have proper indentation. I've tried passing trim_blocks=True and keep_trailing_newline=False without much success.

```
   applications:
      {{ application_name }}:
        version: {{ version }}
        {% if dependencies is not none: -%}
        dependencies:
          {% for key, value in dependencies.items() -%}
            - {{ key }}: {{ value }}
          {% endfor -%}
        {% endif -%}
        {% if departments is not none: -%}
        departments:
          {% for key, value in departments.items() -%}
            - {{ key }}: {{ value }}
          {% endfor -%}
        {% endif -%}
        paid: "yes"
        obsolete: "no"
```

Actual results. **departments** and **paid** blocks do not follow the data structure hierarchy

```
applications:
  appication1:
    version: "1.0"
    dependencies:
      - database: mysql
      - storage: nfs
      departments: <- Indent is not correct
      - accounting: payroll
      paid: "yes" <- Indent is not correct
    obsolete: "no"
```

Expected results. **departments** and **paid** align with **paid**, **version** and etc.

```
applications:
  appication1:
    version: "1.0"
    dependencies:
      - database: mysql
      - storage: nfs
    departments:
      - accounting: payroll
    paid: "yes"
    obsolete: "no"
```

I am wondering what else I could be missing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how i finally solved it:

```
{%- if environment is not none: %}
enviroment:
{%- for key, value in environment.items() %}
  - {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-%}` will eat up all whitespace *after* that bracket (including newlines).  I think that you'll probably want to use the `-` on the opening bracket (`{%-`):

```
   applications:
      {{ application_name }}:
        version: {{ version }}
        {% if dependencies is not none: -%}
        dependencies:
          {% for key, value in dependencies.items() -%}
            - {{ key }}: {{ value }}
          {% endfor -%}
        {% endif -%}
        {%- if departments is not none: %}
        departments:
          {% for key, value in departments.items() -%}
            - {{ key }}: {{ value }}
          {% endfor -%}
        {%- endif %}
        paid: "yes"
        obsolete: "no"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

   ` {%- if environment is not none: %}
    enviroment:
    {%- for key, value in environment.items() %}
      - {{ key }}: {{ value }}
    {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endif %}`