# Avoid indentation on a newline after a set of if+for in a Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

So I have this template:

```
array (
  {% if dict is defined %}
  {% for key, value in dict.items() %}
  '{{ key }}' => {{ value }},
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
),
```

I know I need to attach a dash sign to some of the {% / %} characters but I just can't find the right combination. Here's the expected result:

```
array (
  'key1' => value1,
  'key2' => value2,
  ...
),
```

So far this is the closest combination to what I want:

```
array (
  {% if dict is defined -%}
  {% for key, value in dict.items() -%}
  '{{ key }}' => {{ value }},
  {% endfor -%}
  {% endif -%}
),
```

result:

```
array (
  'key1' => value1,
  'key2' => value2,
  ...
  'keyN' => valueN,
  ), <- this should not be indented
```

Note that I tried the solution mentioned in this similar case:
[Python jinja2 indentention and whitespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732051/python-jinja2-indentention-and-whitespace-issue)

But it doesn't work for me either, resulting in the whole output being written on the same line.

I tried many more combinations but none of them works so far, most of them result in all kay-value pairs being written on the same line. Is there anyone in the crowd who is more experienced with Jinja and knows how to get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you will also have to use the Jinja2 [`trim_blocks`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#high-level-api) environment parameter.

It is here demonstrated in a `debug` task but the same comment line can, of course, be added at the beginning of any **.j2* file treated by the `template` module.

So the magic comment line is this one:

```
#jinja2: trim_blocks:False
```

Also note that, in order to reduce the complexity of the two blocks to control whitespace on, I am using the [`for ... if`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#loop-filtering) construct.

And so given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          #jinja2: trim_blocks:False
          array (
            {%- for key, value in dict.items() if dict is defined %}
            '{{ key }}' => {{ value }},
            {%- endfor %}
          ),
      vars:
        dict: 
          lorem: ipsum
          dolor: sit
```

This gives the output:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "array (\n  'lorem' => ipsum,\n  'dolor' => sit,\n),\n"
}
```